# Why do JDBC calls to stored procedures wrap the call in curly brackets?

Tags: java, jdbc

From Java we'd do something like:
`stmt.execute("SELECT * FROM users");`
But for a stored procedure like:
`stmt.execute("{CALL createUser(?,?,?,?)}");`

Why do we need the `{` and `}` when this is not required in normal SQL?

Comment: The braces are also to escape generic function definitions (as listed in the JDBC specification, with proscribed parameters and order). The driver will then translate that to database specific function calls.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The curly braces are the escape syntax for stored procedures. When the JDBC driver encounters `{call createUser(?,?,?,?)}` , it will translate this escape syntax into the native SQL used by the database to call the stored procedure.

Comment: Follow up question on this, what is the difference between using curly braces and not using them, sometimes when I don't use curly braces Junk Data come in record types in result and it gets fixed when i use curly braces.

Answer (score 7):

JDBC was derived from ODBC. 
Indeed the first jdbc driver was the jdbc to odbc bridge.
So it made sense to use the ODBC syntax. 
The braces themselves indicate a function call, a stored procedure is basically a user 
defined function, so they are wrapped with the braces.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that the braces can be used for other things than function calls, e.g. to (date and time) literals. E.g. `{d '2014-07-03'}`

Answer (score 2):

Here is the official docs on JDBC escape syntax:
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13157_01/wlevs/docs30/jdbc_drivers/sqlescape.html

And some vendor-specific descriptions:

- [Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/java.102/b14355/apxref.htm#i1005144)
- [MS SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/using-sql-escape-sequences)
- [PostgreSQL](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/head/escapes.html)
- [Derby](https://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.8.3.0/ref/rrefjdbc1020262.html)