# How to select data items of a certain length?

Tags: sql

How do I select the row of a column such that the row size is <= 5 ? 
Is there a query for this which will work on most/all databases ?

eg. id, first_name

Select only those people whose firstname is more than 10 characters. Their name is too long ?

Comment: The answer will depend on what RSDM you're using.

Comment: Depends, are you looking for the length in bytes, or the length in characters?

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson - good point. I never knew that bytes was also an option. I am looking for characters.

Comment: @Useyourhead Added both variants to my answer, just in case :)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

If you are bound to use a specific RDBMS then the solution is easy.

```
Use the LENGTH function.
```

Depending upon your database the length function can be LEN, Length, CarLength. Just search google for it.

According to your question

> How do I select the row of a column such that the row size is **<= 5** ?
>   Is there a query for this which will work on most/all databases ?

solution can be

```
SELECT * FROM TableName WHERE LENGTH(name) <= 5
```

If you want something that can work with almost all the database and I assume that the length of your string that you want to fetch is of a significant small length. Example 5 or 8 characters then you can use something like this

```
 SELECT * 
 FROM tab
 WHERE
    colName LIKE ''
 OR colName LIKE '_' 
 OR colName LIKE '__'
 OR colName LIKE '___'
 OR colName LIKE '____'
 OR colName LIKE '_____'
```

This works with almost all major DBMS.

see example:

[SQL Server](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/dc25e/1)

[MySQL](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/13843/2)

[Oracle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/76d01/1)

[Postgre SQL](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/3020b/1)

[SQLite](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/e17b2/1)

Comment: Perhaps you should add, too: `OR colName = ''`

Answer (score 16):

Assuming you want the length in characters, the function names vary with RDBMS;

MySQL: [CHAR_LENGTH()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_char-length).
Oracle: [LENGTH()](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions076.htm).
SQL Server: [LEN()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190329.aspx).
PostgreSQL: [CHAR_LENGTH() or LENGTH()](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-string.html).
SQLite: [LENGTH()](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html).

If you want the length in bytes, it's instead;

MySQL: [LENGTH()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_length).
Oracle: [LENGTHB()](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions076.htm).
SQL Server: [DATALENGTH()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173486.aspx).
PostgreSQL: [OCTET_LENGTH()](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-string.html).

For example, selecting all rows with names longer than 10 *characters* in MySQL would be;

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE CHAR_LENGTH(name) > 10;
```

Comment: SQLite has `LENGTH()` for character length: http://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html

Answer (score 3):

In sql servers TSQL you could use the len function.
eg

```
SELECT * FROM people WHERE LEN(firstname) > 10
```

Where people is the table name.

In mysql the function is called "Length" instead of len.

Answer (score 0):

In case you call from Java, there is portable [JDBC escape](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13634983/why-do-jdbc-calls-to-stored-procedures-wrap-the-call-in-curly-brackets/53504589#53504589) function:

```
select {fn length('some text expression')} from sometable
```