# How to do a wildcard DataTable select with lambda/LINQ using question marks?

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I have a C# DataTable (`_dtOptions`) that looks like this:

[image]

And I have the following in-memory `select`:

```
DataRow[] matchingRows = _dtOptions.Select("OptionID Like 'M00F????'");
```

The reason I'm using `?` instead of `*` is because I want to match only records with exactly 8 characters beginning with `M00F`.

The problem: `matchingRows` is empty after that line of code executes. As you can see in the screenshot, it should be matching quite a number of records.

Note: When I run this query against the underlying `Access` database, I do get expected results back: `select * from Options where OptionID like 'M00F????'`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You need to use LENGTH function for checking length of data in a column. Read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17062065/how-to-select-data-items-of-a-certain-length

Comment: `_dtOptions.Select("LEN(OptionID) = 8 AND OptionID Like 'M00F%'");`

Comment: Use a Regex along with your linq : _dtOptions.AsEnumerable().Where(x => Regex.Match(x,"M00F\d{4}").IsMatch).ToList();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this:

```
DataRow[] matchingRows = _dtOptions.AsEnumerable()
    .Where(x => x.Field<string>("OptionID").Length == 8 &&
        x.Field<string>("OptionID").StartsWith("M00F"))
    .ToArray();
```

Comment: Absolutely perfect, and thanks for keeping it simple. Thank you Hemang.

Answer (score 1):

### Separate your concerns

Your problem arises, because you mix the way your data is stored (DataTable) with the way that you want to process the data (LINQ statements), and possibly also the way that you want to process the result (Display on screen?)

The proper way would be to separate these concerns: separate the way your data is internally kept, from the processing, and processing the result.

In your example, your data is retrieved from a `DataTable`, after which you do some processing, and probably you will do something with the result.

If in future you decide to retrieve similar data from a List, a database, or from a CSV-file, or maybe from the internet, you wouldn't want to change the processing part, nor the part where you do something with the result.

Similarly, if you re-arrange the columns in your DataTable, or name them differently, you wouldn't want to mess up the processing. Think of all the code you would have to check and all unit tests you would have to change, only because you rename a column!

Separating your concerns has some advantages

- The code will be easier to understand: Every concern has exactly one well defined function. You don't need to use a lot of words to define that functionality.
- The code e will be easier to change: for example less changes if your DataTable is replaced by a database;
- Easier to Test: you can test your LINQ statement with a List as input; No need to create DataSets for your test
- Better re-usability: you can re-use your DataTable to extract the data for other purposes. You can re-use your LINQ statement for other input sources.

So let's separate our concerns!

### Back to your question

First of all, you need a class that represents the data that is kept in your `DataTable`. Obviously this is an `IEnumerable` sequence of the data kept in each row of your `DataTable`. Something like this:

```
class MyData
{
    public string OptionId {get; set;}
    public string CatId {get; set;}
    ...
}
```

You could also create a class that represents `a DataRow containing one object of MyData` and a class that represents `a DataTable that contains a sequence of my DataRows`.

Personally I think that these classes won't add a lot of functionality, so I'll write some LINQ like extension functions for `DataRow` and `DataTable` that will convert your table into an enumerable sequence of `MyData`. See [Extension Methods demystified](http://geekswithblogs.net/BlackRabbitCoder/archive/2013/03/08/c.net-little-wonders-extension-methods-demystified.aspx)

```
// Convert a DataRow to a MyData:
public static MyData ToMyData(this DataRow row)
{
    // Todo: check for null row
    return new MyData
    {
        OptionId = row... // TODO implement
        ...
    }
}

// Convert a sequence of DataRows to a sequence of MyData
public static IEnumerable<MyData> ToMyData(this IEnumerable<DataRow> rows)
{
    // TODO: check for null rows
    return rows.Select(row => row.ToMyData());
}

// Convert a DataTable to a sequence of MyData:
public static IEnumerable<MyData> ToMyData(this DataTable table)
{
     // TODO: check for null table
     return table.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().ToMyData();
}
```

So after three one-liner functions, you are able to convert your DataTable into a sequence of MyData, which you can LINQ:

```
DataTable table = ...
IEnumerable<MyData> myItems = table.ToMyData();
```

You want only those `MyData` objects in your table that have an `OptionId` with length 8 and starts with the string "M00F".

Because I sepearated my concerns, the implementation will be very simple:

```
var matchingData = myItems.Where(myItem => myItem.OptionId.Length == 8
                                        && myItem.OptionId.StartsWith("M00F"));
```

Every myItem is an object of MyData.

If you plan to use this concept of `MatchingData` more often, or want to keep in mind that in future you might want to change which data is matching, for instance data starting with "M11F", so if you want to make this requirement better changeable, re-usable, testable (anyway, you know the drill by now), make it an extension function of `MyData`:

```
public static IEnumerable<MyData> WhereMatches(this IEnumerable<MyData> source)
{
    // TODO: check for null source
    return source.Where(item => item.OptionId.Length == 8
    && item.OptionId.StartsWith("M00F"));
}
```

See how easy it will be to test this one! No need for test DataTables, etc. This function will also work if your information comes from a database. Only few changes if you need to match "M11F"

Your complete requirement in one statement:

```
DataTable table = ...
var matchinData = table.ToMyData().WhereMatches();
```

Some side remarks:

- if you want to be certain that you can't put the incorrect DataSet into ToMyData, consider creating special MyDataTable and MyDataRow, derived from DataTable and DataRow. This class hides how the DataTable is organized. Besides it makes sure that you don't put an incorrectly formatted DataTable into your functions. However, in this case the code is so small it seems this will hardly add any useful functionality.
- consider creating functions to convert back: a sequence of MyData into a DataTable, or a sequence of DataRows, which can be used to add rows to an existing DataTable.

Comment: Thank you for the well-thought-out and well-reasoned answer. In the end I went for the short and easy approach.