# Calling Postgresql stored procedure using JDBC

Tags: postgresql, jdbc

Very simple, just raw JDBC

```
            CallableStatement call = con.prepareCall("{ call xyz() }");
            call.execute();
```

Produces

```
          ERROR: xyz() is a procedure
 [java]   Hint: To call a procedure, use CALL.
```

(xyz is indeed a parameterless stored procedure.)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65117089/

Answer (score 0):

```
  con.createStatement().execute("xyz()");
```

seems to work.  Just do not use CallableStatement.