# How to configure Mulesoft (4.4) "stored procedure" component to invoke PostgreSQL Stored Procedure

Tags: mulesoft, anypoint-studio

I am trying to configure mule to invoke a stored procedure in PostgreSQL. Please find the configuration below,

```
<db:stored-procedure doc:name="Stored procedure" doc:id="ace0cc98-d170-4d0c-b7b4-905162b03797" config-ref="Database_Config1">
            <db:sql ><![CDATA[{call sp_employee_generate(:pn_name,:pn_age,:pn_add1,:pn_add2,:pn_add3,:pn_city,:pn_state,:pn_pin,:pn_Mobile_no,:pn_Email_id,:pn_Employee_no)} ]]></db:sql>
            <db:input-parameters ><![CDATA[#[{
            "pn_name":vars.requestParam.p_name,
"pn_age":vars.requestParam.p_age,
"pn_add1":vars.requestParam.p_add1,
"pn_add2":vars.requestParam.p_add2,
"pn_add3":vars.requestParam.p_add3,
"pn_city":vars.requestParam.p_city,
"pn_state":vars.requestParam.p_state,
"pn_pin":vars.requestParam.p_pin,
"pn_Mobile_no":vars.requestParam.p_Mobile_no,
"pn_Email_id":vars.requestParam.p_Email_id}]]]></db:input-parameters>
            <db:output-parameters >
                <db:output-parameter key="pn_Employee_no" type="VARCHAR" />
            </db:output-parameters>
        </db:stored-procedure>
```

However, while testing I am receiving the following error,

```
Message               : ERROR: sp_employee_generate(character varying, integer, character varying, character varying, character varying, character varying, character varying, character varying, integer, character varying) is a procedure
  Hint: To call a procedure, use CALL.
  Position: 15
```

Can you please help correcting the configuration to overcome the above error.

Kind Regards,

Comment: Please share the database connector configuration, JDBC driver the application is using and the version of the PostresSQL engine.

Comment: And also share the data types of the parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because of the curly braces around the statements. The Postgres driver, by default, treats those statements as function calls and translates the statement. You can remove them to use native sql:

```
call sp_employee_generate(:pn_name,:pn_age,:pn_add1,:pn_add2,:pn_add3,:pn_city,:pn_state,:pn_pin,:pn_Mobile_no,:pn_Email_id,:pn_Employee_no)
```

Or you can set a connection property `escapeSyntaxCallMode` to `call`: https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/publicapi/org/postgresql/jdbc/EscapeSyntaxCallMode.html

You can do this via a Datasource config similar to:

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.postgresql...."> 
    <property name="URL" value='"jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/bla />
    <property name="User" value="<USER>" />
    <property name="Password" value="<PASSWORD>" />
    <property name="ConnectionProperties">
        <value>
            escapeSyntaxCallMode:call
        </value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

There is a good explanation and some more alternatives here: ["x is a procedure, use "call"" when I am already using call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65116924/x-is-a-procedure-use-call-when-i-am-already-using-call)

Comment: Thank you Ryan removing the curly braces did the trick